# What is less doing with rpm, and how do I get that text without rpm

Tags: grep, rpm, less

When I execute `less package.rpm`, less shows me all sorts of meta info about the package. What is less exactly doing - does it have built in code to be able to extract meta info, or is an rpm structured in a way that the first part just looks like a text file?

I would assume the former, since `head` is not so helpful here. But to get to the *real* question: If I would like to `grep` through this meta data less showing me, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you browse through the `less` man page, you'll notice `less` has an INPUT PREPROCESSOR feature.

`echo $LESSOPEN` to view the location of this preprocessor, and use `less`/`vim`/`cat` to view its contents.

On my machine this preprocessor is `/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh` and it includes the following for rpms:

```
*.rpm) rpm -qpivl --changelog -- "$1"; handle_exit_status $?
```

In effect, `less` hands off openning the file to `rpm`, and shows you the pagination of its output.

Obviously, to grep through this info, simply grep the output of rpm directly:

```
grep "foo" < <(rpm -qpivl --changelog -- bar.rpm)
```

Or in general (thanks OrangeDog)

```
grep "foo" < <(lesspipe.sh bar.rpm)
```

**Note:** `$LESSOPEN` Does not simply hold the location of `lesspipe.sh` - it begins with a `|` and ends with a `%s` so invoking it directly would result in errors.

Comment: Why not `grep "foo" < <($LESSOPEN bar.rpm)`? Or maybe even just `$LESSOPEN bar.rpm | grep "foo"`.

Answer (score 4):

> If I would like to grep through this meta data less showing me, how can I accomplish this?

very simply; if you want to grep on "Version" for example:

```
less your.rpm | grep "Version"
```

Note that less is using the `rpm` command; so better skip using less; and use `rpm` commands; like:

```
rpm -qip /path/to/uninstalled/rpm
rpm -qi installed.rpm
```